# Two Asynctasks following each other

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am having trouble working with asynctasks.  The problem is that I need data from one asynctask to be loaded into a static variable before another asynctask begins since asynctask2 needs that static variable.  I tried using this code to stall asynctask2 but it doesn't even show up in my log cat:

```
//geocode is the first asynctask                                                                                      
          while(geocode.getStatus().equals(android.os.AsyncTask.Status.PENDING))
            {try {;
            wait(100);
            Log.i("waiting", "waiting");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
```

Comment: WHy are you using 2 async tasks then?  If you need to wait for the 1st to be done before doing the second, why not do the second task as part of the first one?  Or at least launch it from there?

Comment: Agreed with Gabe.  Put both things you need to do all inside doInBackground() of the first task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `onPostExecute` of the first AsyncTask to start the next one, that way you know it has finished and it is safe to start the next one. I would however try to think of a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks that solves that problem.  If you have any suggestions I would be very grateful.  I'm trying to get geocoding info from google and then I have to check that data to see if it has been added to my database.  As far as I can tell I'm going to need to run this on multiple threads in tandem no matter what.  If you know a better way to do this please enlighten me.  Thanks.

Comment: well like the others have said you should just do everything in the one async task